# Xcode 6 can't find framework header files when project name contains spaces

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using the Parse and PubNub SDK in my project called `My Sample App` and since I updated my Xcode to 6.3.1 I can't run the project because Xcode doesn't find the header files. I had the same issue with the previous version, but then I just needed to delete and add them again to make it work, unfortunately it doesn't work now. I also tried to delete the `Library Search Path` and `Framework Search Path` without any success. Is there any trick that fixes this issue?

This is the exact error:

```
'PNImports.h' file not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `$(PROJECT_DIR)` to your `Library Search Path` in project settings AND select `recursive` option 
[image]

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately doesn't work, got the same error.

Comment: Do you select recursive option?

Answer (score 0):

Surround `Library Search Path` with single quotes

Comment: How you mean it? Actually it's blank. Or just put '' there?

Comment: Sorry I understood that your project has Library Search Path with spaces there. In that case quotes are helpful

Comment: But where this name appears? Could you replace it by `$(PROJECT_DIR)`?

Comment: This is the project name. It appears everywhere. I tried $(PROJECT_DIR) but unfortunately doesn't works.